# tf.reshape() not giving exppected result

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, flatten

Here is the code of model including convolutional layers and training function using tensorflow. After coding all the layers of model, flatten layer  is not giving an expected output which contains tf.reshape(). Please help me .

```
def model(self, inp):
    # Layer 3
    layer3_conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(layer2_max_pool1, self.__W[3], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding=self.padding)
    layer3_relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(layer3_conv1, self.__b[3]))
    layer3_max_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(layer3_relu1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding=self.padding)
    w4 = (layer3_max_pool1.get_shape()[1:]).as_list()
    print("layer3maxpool shape is ",layer3_max_pool1.shape)
    print("w4 shape is ",w4)

    # Flatten
    print ("x is :",np.prod(w4))
    flatten = tf.reshape(layer3_max_pool1, [ -1,np.prod(w4)])
    print(" Flatten shape is",flatten.shape)

    # Fully Connected Network
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flatten, self.__W[4]) + self.__b[4])
    print(fc1.shape)
    out = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc1, self.__W[5]) + self.__b[5])

    # print(out.get_shape().as_list())
    return out
```

Output is :

```
layer3maxpool shape is  (?, 45, 58, 256)
> w4 shape is  [45, 58, 256]
> x is : 668160
Flatten shape is (?, 668160)
> (?, 1024)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to study [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it currently stands, your post is `This doesn't work. Please fix it for me`. We don't usually answer such questions here. Instead, please, rephrase your post to ask an actual question, debug your code and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please specify what shape were you expecting, the given code is doing what it should, the incoming layer has a variable or flexible shape for its first dimension.

Please specify what shape are you expecting

Comment: I want to ask why tf.reshape() is giving ? in the output that is flatten, because of this further processig is not done.